# How to add sharedpreferences in an audio player mainactivity code

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am developing an android music player, but don't know how to use sharedpreferences in my code.
I want to save the last song on music player so that when next time open the app it shows the last audio on player. But now it lost the preveious song from the player. Here is the code of my project. URI code is given here.

```
private void initPlayer(final int position) {

    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    String sname = mySongs.get(position).getName().replace(".mp3", "").replace(".m4a", "").replace(".wav", "").replace(".m4b", "");
    songTitle.setText(sname);
    Uri songResourceUri = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), songResourceUri); // create and load mediaplayer with song resources
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            String totalTime = createTimeLabel(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
            totTime.setText(totalTime);
            mSeekBar.setMax(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            playIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);

        }
    });

    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            int curSongPoition = position;
            // code to repeat songs until the
            if (curSongPoition < mySongs.size() - 1) {
                curSongPoition++;
                initPlayer(curSongPoition);
            } else {
                curSongPoition = 0;
                initPlayer(curSongPoition);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> //method to get stored song from SharedPreferences

```
public static String song_path(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = act.getSharedPreferences("SHAREDpREFname", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString("song_path", null);
}
```

> //method to store previous song

```
public static void set_song_path(Context context, String path) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor saver = act.getSharedPreferences("SHAREDpREFname", context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

    saver.putString("song_path", path);
    saver.commit();
}

private void initPlayer(final int position) {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    String sname = mySongs.get(position).getName().replace(".mp3", "").replace(".m4a", "").replace(".wav", "").replace(".m4b", "");
    songTitle.setText(sname);
    Uri songResourceUri = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
    set_song_path(your_context,songResourceUri.toString());//this is to save 
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), songResourceUri); // create and load mediaplayer with song resources
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            String totalTime = createTimeLabel(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
            totTime.setText(totalTime);
            mSeekBar.setMax(mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            playIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);

        }
    });

    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            int curSongPoition = position;
            // code to repeat songs until the
            if (curSongPoition < mySongs.size() - 1) {
                curSongPoition++;
                initPlayer(curSongPoition);
            } else {
                curSongPoition = 0;
                initPlayer(curSongPoition);
            }
        }
    });
  }
```

To retreive the song path call `String path=song_path(your_context);` for Uri  `Uri savedsongResourceUri = Uri.parse(song_path(your_context));`

Comment: What should i put in your_context? Bro i am new to Android studio. Can you please give your email id.

Comment: This is your context .if you are calling it on an activity ,replace it with "this" so :String path=song_path(this)

Comment: Where should i put the retrive code. Can you give me your email id. It will be helpful for me

Comment: anywhere you wish  to play the last played song.it could be on oncreate .

Answer (score 0):

Use below class to store shared preferences

```
public class SharedPreferencesUtils {
    private static final String TAG = SharedPreferencesUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    /* store lastplayed song*/
    public static void setPreviousSongInSharedPrefs(Context context, String songName) {
        try {
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefsEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
            sharedPrefsEditor.putString("PREVIOUS_SONG" , songName);
            sharedPrefsEditor.apply();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /* get store previous song*/
    public static String getPreviousSongFromSharedPrefs(Context context) {
        String previousSong = "";
        try {
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            previousSong = sharedPrefs.getString("PREVIOUS_SONG" , "default value");
            return previousSong;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return previousSong;
    }

}
```

to call respective method use below code:

to store song name: `SharedPreferencesUtils.setPreviousSongInSharedPrefs(getContext(), songName);`

to get previous song name: `String songname = SharedPreferencesUtils.getPreviousSongFromSharedPrefs(getContext());`

Comment: Is there any other way to save data of last played song?